# Add Full Text Search using Azure Search, Azure SQL, Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, full-text-indexing, azure-cognitive-search

I'm running a site as an Azure Web App, using Azure SQL, Azure Search, and Azure Blob Storage.

Currently the Azure Search index (for the document search) is built using an indexer drawing data from multiple SQL tables (via a view) to associate permissions and other meta data indirectly associated with the documents, including the url to the doc in Azure Blob Storage.

The newly released update to Azure Search seems to allow full-text searching of blobs which is great, but the data source has to be changed to the blob storage container, missing out on the additional meta that would be populated by my SQL view.

Can a Search index document be populated by more than one data source, or can a second indexer update an existing search document (to add the full-text data to the document)?

I've looked at trying to capture the data and creating the full text within the SQL db at document upload, but on Azure web apps there doesn't seem to be a suitable parser, and Azure SQL Full text index doesn't support Word or PDF docs which are mostly what I'm uploading.

Is it possible to modify the indexer to incorporate Azure Blob Storage full text indexing, or should I be looking for a completely different approach?

Answer (score 3):

Azure Search indexes can be populated by multiple indexers, or even by a mix of indexer and your own code calling indexing API. (Specifically, indexers use `mergeOrUpload` indexing action.)

You just need to make sure that both SQL and blob indexers agree on the document key, so they update the same documents.
HTH!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it gave me the confidence to continue down that path and I'm now having mixed success.

Comment: I creating a new indexer with its own index, so I wouldn't corrupt my original SQL source index, and once I got that working I realised how important your second comment regarding the document key was.
Unless you know otherwise I think the only document key that can be used is the filename.
This needs to be encoded so I've used the 'base64EncodeKeys': true parameter, but this doesn't always match the encoded filename generated by the SQL Indexer (usually if there are less common characters).
Also the 'Title' fieldname generated by the SQL indexer is overwritten with null by the Blob Indexer.

Comment: 1. Please send me details on what names don't match - perhaps there're some differences in the strings (like a trailing slash)? eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain.

2. To avoid overwriting, the set of fields in your blob datasource and SQL datasource need to be disjoint, except the key. If your data contains a field Title with null value, we interpret it as you wanting to clear that field from the index, which is a legitimate scenario.